# Pandas/Statsmodel OLS predicting future values

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I've been trying to get a prediction for future values in a model I've created.  I have tried both OLS in pandas and statsmodels.  Here is what I have in statsmodels:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
endog = pd.DataFrame(dframe['monthly_data_smoothed8'])
smresults = sm.OLS(dframe['monthly_data_smoothed8'], dframe['date_delta']).fit()
sm_pred = smresults.predict(endog)
sm_pred
```

The length of the array returned is equal to the number of records in my original dataframe but the values are not the same.  When I  do the following using pandas I get no values returned.

```
from pandas.stats.api import ols
res1 = ols(y=dframe['monthly_data_smoothed8'], x=dframe['date_delta'])
res1.predict
```

(Note that there is no .fit function for OLS in Pandas) Could somebody shed some light on how I might get future predictions from my OLS model in either pandas or statsmodel-I realize I must not be using .predict properly and I've read the multiple other problems people have had but they do not seem to apply to my case.

**edit** I believe 'endog' as defined is incorrect-I should be passing the values for which I want to predict; therefore I've created a date range of 12 periods past the last recorded value.  But still I miss something as I am getting the error:

```
matrices are not aligned
```

**edit** here is a snippet of data, the last column (in red) of numbers is the date delta which is a difference in months from the first date:

```
month   monthly_data    monthly_data_smoothed5  monthly_data_smoothed8  monthly_data_smoothed12 monthly_data_smoothed3  date_delta
0   2011-01-31  3.711838e+11    3.711838e+11    3.711838e+11    3.711838e+11    3.711838e+11    0.000000
1   2011-02-28  3.776706e+11    3.750759e+11    3.748327e+11    3.746975e+11    3.755084e+11    0.919937
2   2011-03-31  4.547079e+11    4.127964e+11    4.083554e+11    4.059256e+11    4.207653e+11    1.938438
3   2011-04-30  4.688370e+11    4.360748e+11    4.295531e+11    4.257843e+11    4.464035e+11    2.924085
```

Comment: without your data, one can only speculate. please post a self-contained example that includes code to generate your data. see http://sscce.org/ for more info

Comment: ok...I tried to post a copy and pasted data frame from an ipython output but of course it doesn't format correctly...

Comment: do `df.to_dict` and paste that

Comment: Your first set of code looks ok.  Why would you expect the values to be the same?  Maybe look at `smresults.summary()` to see how well the model is fit.

Comment: It's not that I expect them to be the same really, it's just that it is returning values for 42 periods but I don't know which ones and the values are e+22 which is way too high.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your issue here is that statsmodels doesn't add an intercept by default, so your model doesn't achieve much of a fit.  To solve it in your code would be something like this:

```
dframe = pd.read_clipboard() # your sample data
dframe['intercept'] = 1
X = dframe[['intercept', 'date_delta']]
y = dframe['monthly_data_smoothed8']

smresults = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

dframe['pred'] = smresults.predict()
```

Also, for what it's worth, I think the statsmodel formula api is much nicer to work with when dealing with DataFrames, and adds an intercept by default (add a `- 1` to remove).  See below, it should give the same answer.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

smresults = smf.ols('monthly_data_smoothed8 ~ date_delta', dframe).fit()

dframe['pred'] = smresults.predict()
```

Edit:

To predict future values, just pass new data to `.predict()`  For example, using the first model:

```
In [165]: smresults.predict(pd.DataFrame({'intercept': 1, 
                                          'date_delta': [0.5, 0.75, 1.0]}))
Out[165]: array([  2.03927604e+11,   2.95182280e+11,   3.86436955e+11])
```

On the intercept - there's nothing encoded in the number `1` it's just based on the math of OLS (an intercept is perfectly analogous to a regressor that always equals 1), so you can pull the value right off the summary.  Looking at the statsmodels [docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html), an alternative way to add an intercept would be:

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
```

Comment: Hello-thanks! a couple questions-the second code worked, however I'm wondering how to get a prediction for date_delta's beyond the range of my data.  The dframe['intercept'] = 1 is returning an error of `intercept' not in index`.  Further I am able to see the intercept precisely from the model summary, should I use that or does '1' encode something? Thanks again!

Comment: sorry! I what is happening with the intercept! I just need to figure out how to predict future periods with this model now...

Comment: @pythonista - on the error - make sure that `type(dframe)` is a pandas a DataFrame, you shouldn't be getting that error.  See edit for answers to your other questions.

Comment: very nice, thank you so much-I did a bunch of ewma's with different spans and am predicting future values using ewma and I wanted to compare it to OLS predictions on the original data and on the smoothed data...no idea what to trust but thanks for helping me with this piece!